# Inheritance of Properties in C#

Tags: c#, c#-10.0

How to prevent inheritance of a property, so that it is no longer counted in the instantiated object.
In the following example, I want object instance B to contain just two properties, namely MyCommonProperty and Name.

Properties must remain public

```
public class A
{
    public string MyCommonProperty { get; set; }
    public string MyClassASpecificProperty { get; set; }
}
public class B : A
{   
    public string Name { get; set; }    
}
```

Comment: make the other property private. if it needs to stay public, though: tough luck; you can't.

Comment: it must remain public

Comment: Then you're basically trying to break inheritance. If someone can write `A a = new B();` then they can use `a.MyClassASpecificProperty`. You might want to consider having the *real* base class `A`, and then a separate derived class to just add `MyClassASpecificProperty`.

Comment: @diaz15: Then inheritance isn't the right tool for the job.  If `B` "is an" `A` then `B` would have the properties of `A`.  Maybe instead `B` "has an" `A`?  Favoring composition over inheritance?

Comment: If B is an A, then B has the members of A. If members of A make no sense for B, reconsider using inheritance for this scenario.

Comment: What does "no longer counted in" mean? Does it mean that it can no longer be set, or that you do not want it to even be visible (such as through intellisense, serialization, etc)?

Comment: @DavidL I don't even want it to be visible

Comment: There is nothing in the language that allows that type of behavior. You should reconsider your hierarchy if that's your goal, as others have said.

Comment: Yes I see, the solution if used a base class as Carlo Capuano said,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can't, but you can:

create a Base Class X with only "MyCommonProperty" and have both A and B inherit from it adding their property.

or

"MyCommonProperty" is actually in a interface which both class implement

Comment: Yes this is the fallback solution I was considering using.

Answer (score 4):

Change the modifier of the properties you don't want inherited types to access to `private`.

Comment: it must remain public

Comment: That would not be possible.  Properties and methods are either visible or hidden from their derived types.  The property must be private.  If you need to have controlled access to the property, then I would convert it into a private field and use a public method to get access to it.  Another thing you could do is use two different interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use inheritance when inheritance isn't applicable. Two unrelated classes can still have a common interface without inheritance if you specify an explicit `interface`:

```
public interface ICommonThings
{
    string SomeProperty { get; set; }
}

public class Thing1 : ICommonThings
{
    public string Thing1Stuff { get; set; }
    public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
}

public class Thing2 : ICommonThings
{
    public string Thing2Stuff { get; set; }
    public string SomeProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Interface is not useful in my scenario, I want to use something like sealed

Comment: @diaz15 in that case consider having an abstract base class to expose the common property, with the derived types adding their own members; note that it's hard to tell whether your scenario actually warrants the use of inheritance - if you can't say "B is an A" (inheritance), see if "B _has an_ A" (composition) makes more sense for your case.

Comment: I use TPT and Dto inheritance, there are fields I don't want to expose, use of base classes completes things a bit, but hey I have to deal with it. thank you

Answer (score 1):

In the same line as Mathieu Guindon suggested, you could use explicit interface implementation to "hide" the property, but I don't see it be a good idea. The trickery would go as follow:

```
public interface IFoo
{
    public string MyCommonProperty { get; set; }
    public string MyClassASpecificProperty { get; set; }
}

public class A : IFoo
{
    public string MyCommonProperty { get; set; }
    string string MyClassASpecificProperty { get; set; }
}

public class B : IFoo
{
    public string MyCommonProperty { get; set; }
    public string Name{ get; set; }

    string IFoo.MyClassASpecificProperty { get; set;}
}
```